# Connecting Centos 7 to Android phone

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, centos7, mtp

I'm trying to connect a Centos 7 operating system to a Moto3G Android phone (running Android v6 - marshmallow)

libmtp is installed

```
Package libmtp-1.1.6-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Most of the searches on the Internet suggest using mtp-detect but in my case:

```
bash: mtp-detect: command not found
```

I can see the phone using dmesg

```
[ 6446.771306] usb 1-1.2: Product: XT1039
[ 6446.771309] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: motorola
```

I installed jmtpfs (using yum) which gives me the following

```
jmtpfs
No mtp devices found.
```

I tried installing [go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs/) using GO but get the following

```
$ ./gopath/bin/go-mtpfs bob &
[1] 21633
$ 2017/05/03 13:06:18 detect failed: no MTP devices found

[1]+  Exit 1                  ./gopath/bin/go-mtpfs bob
```

If anyone has any advice or suggestions on progressing this I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Access Android MTP or Other MTP devices in CentOS 7 Linux OS

> Install mtp libs and utilities in CentOS
>
> Login as root and install fuse, jmtpfs, libmtp as following:

```
$yum install fuse, jmtpfs, libmtp
```

**Steps to Mount/Load MTP formatted devices(e.g android 7 nougat)**

> Login as root Create a directory to mount MTP device:

```
$mkdir /media/mtp-device
```

> Connect android device to the USB cable, Unlock the android phone,        Swipe down from the top of the phone screen. You
>   should see a notification "USB ...", Tap that notification.  You should
>   see a menu titled "Use USB to...", select "Transfer files(MTP)" Option...
>
> To list all the available mtp devices(eg.
>   android 7 nougat), issue command jmtpfs in root session

```
$jmtpfs -l
```

> each mtp device is listed with busnum, devnum information. Mount
>   device as below:

```
$jmtpfs -device=<busnum>,<devnum> /media/mtp-device #If this option not specified, then the first device found isused.
```

> or

```
$jmtpfs /media/mtp-device #All files will be present in /media/mtp-device location,but it will be accessible to the root only.
```

**2. Access/Copy Data from MTP device**

> Now you can access files of android devices mounted on
>   /media/mtp-device folder, but you cannot copy to other folder. To copy
>   files, you need to allow other user as below:

```
$jmtpfs -o allow_other ~/my-android7
```

> Now you can copy the data from ~/my-android7 location to your folders.

**3. Removing or Un-mounting the Device from Linux System**

> First un-mount the allow_other location

```
$fusermount -u ~/my-android7
```

> Finally un-mount the device at root folder.

```
$fusermount -u /media/mtp-device
```